# A store has n customers and anyone can visit them any time throughout the year

Tags: data-structures

A store has n customers and anyone can visit them any time throughout the year. Data is stored in a file. Design a data structure to find if a given person visited on a date or not.

Could anyone suggest data structure I shall use in this case?

Comment: `Data is stored in a file. Design a data structure...` - Are you asking for a serialization format or a data structure? Two different requirements.

Comment: data structure .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this: Every customer is stored in one line while you include the customer name first and then the date. You can split them with commas or something.
These are some examples

```
Name,Date
Name, Date
Name|Date
Name | Date
```

Just choose something that will be the easiest for you to use and to retrieve the information correctly with using string `.split` or `.substring`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement does not state whether or not a customer may visit the store numerous times during the year so assuming that they can I would use a `Map` data-structure, where the key is the name of the customer and the value is the set of dates the customer visited the store. The data can be stored in the file using XML.